# Debugging Designer processing in VS 2008

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, designer

I have a public property set in my form of type `ListE<T>` where:

```
public class ListE<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

Yeah, it's a mouthful, but that's what the Designer requires for it to show up as an editable collection in the Properties window. Which it does! So, I click the little [..] button to edit the collection, and then click Add to add an item to the collection.

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Now, this is a very basic List, little more than an expanding array. The only part that comes close to arithmetic in the whole thing is in the expand function, and even that uses a left shift rather than a multiplication, so that won't overflow. This all makes me think that this exception is being raised inside the Designer, perhaps caused by some small inattention to implementation detail on my part, but I can't find a way to test or debug that scenario. Does anyone have any smart ideas?

EDIT: Yes, I can use the property successfully, well even manually, ie. in the `OnLoad` handler, and I suppose that's what I'll have to resort to if I can't get this working, but that wouldn't be ideal. :(

Comment: It is not related to your problem, but be aware that you can only specify that ListE<T> implements IList<T>.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but List<T> from the standard library has the exact same signature. If you go type "List<T>" and press F12 in VS, it'll take you to a reconstituted definition.

Comment: Infact, IList<T> itself implements the other generic interfaces along with IEnumerable, so I could cut that down as just ListE<T> : IList<T>, IList, but this way is more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand what's motivating you to attempt to reinvent the List<T> wheel in that way, but to answer your question: I would add a line "System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()" to the constructor of your class.

Then try to use it in the designer, and you'll get a popup asking you if you want to attach a debugger.  Attach a second instance of Visual Studio as a debugger, and you'll be able to set some breakpoints in your code and start debugging.

Comment: Reimplementing wheels can be fun. There's also no polymorphicly sound way of extending any of the base collections to include events because none of the functions defined are overrideable, hence if I cast it back to the original class, I get no events again.

Comment: And for the record, among other things it was trying to use CopyTo() for some reason, and I hadn't implemented it. Fix that first, then see where we go from there...

Answer (score 0):

One place to start would be that it may be doing math with your ListE`1::Count property. If that has some subtle flaw (i.e. it is more complicated than return this.innerList.Count) it could be causing the designer to arithmetic overflow on some operation. Normally arithmetic overflows do not occur unless specifically asked for using the

```
checked
{
   // ...
}
```

syntax.

Comment: My Count property is a simple one: public int Count { get { return _maxIndex + 1; } } where _maxIndex is the last element in the array.

Comment: I also definitely don't have any checked {} code either, so that only proves it's happening somewhere in the Designer doesn't it?

Comment: @monoxide: it could be your _maxIndex + 1 is overflowing, or the way they USE your _maxIndex+1 (say it is Int32.MaxValue) overflows. Most importantly I'm not entirely sure how you go about debugging this.

Comment: Joe solved how to go about debugging it, as for what was overflowing, it was _list.GetUpperBound(0) * 2 in my expanding method. Somehow the (protected) list was getting set to a zero length array by the designer. Best guess, it was trying to evaluate ((uint) -1) * 2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add the Debugger.Break(); call to your code to debug it.  You can just open a different instance of VS and attach to the one that you using it in and you should be able to debug it with no issues (just make sure that you have the symbols loaded).